# Spring MVC with multiple view resolvers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, facelets

I tried to use 2 view resolvers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.evgeni.dfr.controller" />

    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="false" />
        <property name="viewClass" value="com.evgeni.drf.faces.FacesView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml" />

        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
        <property name="order" value="0" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The application always uses only the one with the lowest order and not the other. In the current case if my controller return "someView" the app will respond with `The requested resource (/MyProject/WEB-INF/views/someView.jsp) is not available.` even if there is "pages/someView.xhtml".

Spring version - 3.2.3

Edit:
If I have 2 methods in controller and methodA returns "viewA" and methodB returns "viewB". And we have viewA.jsp in 'views' folder and viewB.xhtml in 'pages'.

Case1: UrlBasedViewResolver -> order=1,InternalResourceViewResolver -> order=2

methodA -> `The requested resource (/MyProject/WEB-INF/pages/viewA.xhtml) is not available.`;

```
methodB -> OK
```

Case2: UrlBasedViewResolver -> order=2,InternalResourceViewResolver -> order=1

methodA -> OK ;

```
methodB -> `The requested resource (/MyProject/WEB-INF/views/viewB.jsp) is not available.`;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the order priority. The `ViewResolver` with the highest order is the last resolver in the chain. Since you gave the `InternalResourceViewResolver` an order of `0`, it will be the first resolver in the chain and the `InternalResourceViewResolver` will resolve the view whatever view name is returned. So, if you want multiple resolvers, the `InternalResourceViewResolver` must be the resolver with the highest order.

Change the `InternalResourceViewResolver` order value to `2` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.evgeni.dfr.controller" />

    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="false" />
        <property name="viewClass" value="com.evgeni.drf.faces.FacesView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
        <property name="order" value="2" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**EDIT :**

After checking the javadoc, it seems that these two resolvers cannot be chained since the `InternalResourceViewResolver` is a `UrlBasedViewResolver` (InternalResourceViewResolver extends UrlBasedViewResolver). Both resolver  always match the returned value. I think you will need something custom to be able to do this.

Comment: Check my edit. What is your use case. Why are you using those two UrlBasedViewResolver.

Answer (score 1):

Chage order in InternalResourceViewResolver from 0 to 1. InternalResourceViewResolver must have largest order (lower priority)

Comment: As I explained only the view resolver with the lower order is available. If I do that the app will always search for view in 'pages' with suffix = xhtml and will throw an error if one is not found there...